# Add before filter from basecontroller in a class where i have already extended Devise:registrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am overriding the Devise:RegistrationController and i need to add a before filter authentication function which is in the BaseController of my app how to add that before filter . i am facing this problem as i extended the Devise:RegistrationsController and unable to extend the basecontroller

Comment: Write a separate concern with the method you need in it. Then include that concern in both controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Create a concern, then include that concern in both controllers:

```
## app/controllers/concerns/concern_with_the_method_i_want.rb

module ConcernWithTheMethodIWant
  def method
    return 'This is the method'
  end
end
```

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  include ConcernWIthTheMethodIWant
end
```

```
class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationController
  include ConcernWithTheMethodIWant
end
```

This will let you do:

```
BaseController.new.method
=> 'This is the method'

Devise:RegistrationController.new.method
=> 'This is the method'
```

Comment: That should probably be something more like `class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationController`